# zip a file and move it gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am trying zip the contents in the module, exclude the builds folder but it is not running. I do `println` outside the task and that works but nothing will print inside the task.

```
task fullZip(type: Zip) {
    baseName = 'client' //name of the module
    from 'client' //name of the module
    exclude 'build'
    into '../docker/client'
    doFirst { println 'before zip' }
    doLast { println 'after zip' }

}
```

This is a multi module project and I have ran `gradle clean build` and `gradle build` The other modules work just fine but their task is to copy a jar and I use `assemble.dependsOn` at the end of those tasks. That will not work in this case.

I just want to zip up the module and move it to a different directory where I will unzip it.

Comment: You should [**never** call `execute` on tasks](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-call-a-task-from-another-task-with-dependencies/5961/2)! It is not part of the public Gradle API. Instead, let Gradle execute the task by specifying it via command line or by registering task dependencies.

Comment: @lu.koerfer Ok I removed execute. I still cannot get this task to run.

Comment: How do you call Gradle and what is the output? How is your project structure? Please add those details to your question.

Comment: @lu.koerfer please see update

Comment: Do you want to call this independently (via `gradle fullZip`) or as a part of the regular build lifecycle (whenever you call `gradle build`)? Please add the output of a `gradle build` invocation.

Comment: @lu.koerfer I added the task to buildscript in the module and got an error saying `Could not get unknown property 'fullZip' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.`

I want to just run `gradle build` and the whole projects works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164755/discussion-between-drew1208-and-lu-koerfer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary from chat discussion:

```
task fullZip(type: Zip) {
    baseName = 'client'
    from projectDir
    exclude 'build'
    destinationDir = file('../docker/client')
}

build.dependsOn fullZip
```

The main problem was the relative path in the `from` parameter, which did work because is is interpreted relative to the project directory.

Also, according to [the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip:into(java.lang.Object)), the `into` method ...

> Specifies the destination directory *inside* the archive for the files. The destination is evaluated as per `Project.file(java.lang.Object)`. Don't mix it up with `AbstractArchiveTask.getDestinationDir()` which specifies the output directory for the archive.

Those two methods were mixed up. Finally, the task was added to the build lifecycle via a task dependency registration.